# Vertically center caret/selection according to line-height

Tags: css, html, google-chrome

I am trying to get the selection (blue) and caret to be vertically aligned with the text. I have `font: 16px/44px` set on the gray `contenteditable` div.

On Chrome 41, the caret has the same height as the selection. On FF and IE the caret has the same height as the text (16px).

[image: Vertical alignment of caret/select in HTML5 contenteditable (Chrome 41)]

Any ideas?

Comment: please post some code

Comment: It is really only that -- a `<div contenteditable="true" style="font: 16px/44px arial" />`